# How to prove $\Delta : X \to X \times_Y X$ is quasi-compact for $X$ noetherian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme, $f: X \to Y$ consider the fibred product $X \times_Y X$. I would like to know how to show the diagonal morphism $\Delta :  X \to X \times_Y X$ is quasi-compact. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Do you know non-trivial examples? What about examples where a condition is violated and the conclusion does not hold?

Answer (score 0):

To check that $\Delta : X \to X\times_Y X$ is quasicompact, [it is enough to show](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01KO) that the intersection of any two open affine subsets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ is quasicompact. Can you show this? (Can you show that any open subset of $\text{Spec }A$ is quasicompact if $A$ is a Noetherian ring?)